# Python/Pylons - Session Handling - User Session not active anymore

Tags: python, session, exception, pylons

I use Pylons for the Session Handling on my Project. If an user session is not active anymore, the user get a 500 Server Error on FireBug. Now i want inform the user that this session is inactive and that he had to login again.

I can't find where the Session is checked and the 500 Error is generated. Has someone an idea?

I use the default Pylons Settings for my Sessioncontroller ([docs.PylonsProject](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons_framework/dev/sessions.html))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pylons you wrote your own auth code (or at least modify it if you use something like repoze who&what). so you should check your code where did you put that chunk of code that returns 500 Error.

btw i saw that you posted a link from pylonsproject. pylonsproject != pylons.

so if you are using pyramid (and you think you are using pylons) you also wrote a code that returns 500 Error. you should look for class called something like "AuthenticationPolicy". i have my in MYPROJECT/resources.py. there you have a method "unauthenticated_userid". you should look there.

if you posted your project structure i could help you more.